# How to have variable in a Linq Where clause?

Tags: linq, where-clause

This should be a simple think that I´m missing, but have tried everything to solve....
Basically I´m exploring Linq and:

This works:

`List<Project> proj = Repo.Projects.Where(p => p.ID < 3  ).ToList();`

But this does not work:

```
int i =3;
List<Project> proj = Repo.Projects.Where(p => p.ID < i  ).ToList();
```

This works:

```
proj = Repo.Projects.Where(p => p.ID ==  1 ).FirstOrDefault();
```

But this does not work:

```
int i =1;
proj = Repo.Projects.Where(p => p.ID ==  i ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Get the following message from dotnetfifddle:

```
Attempt by method 'DynamicClass.lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, Project)' to access type 'Program+<>c__DisplayClass0' failed.
```

What I´m doing wrong???

Comment: What is the context? Is this Linq-to-Objects, Linq-to-Entities (Entity Framework) or something else? Note that the functionality of different Linq implementations varies. The message says you're using `dynamic` which (to my knowledge) isn't used in LtO or LtE so I'll need more information.

Comment: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/why-am-i-getting-this-error

Comment: Hi Dai, this is a very simple program, all inside a 40 lines dotnetfiddle test. Only objects: I created a dummy class Project, a Repo class with a List<Projects> with just 4 Projects instances and a method to get the list as querable. Then a I tested these Linq expressions. Using System; System.Collections.Generic;
and System.Linq only.

Comment: Full program at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pEIKkK